Macro to consolidate list of text from active x check boxes to specific cell
I have a form with multiple active x check boxes and want a consolidated list of the text next to the check boxes serrated by commas to appear in a specific cell D9 on the same worksheet. Is this possible?
Tried below, all I get is the error message:
Private Sub Macro42()
On Error GoTo M

Dim ans As String
Dim Anss As String
For Each xcontrol In Controls
If TypeName(xcontrol) = "Checkbox" And xcontrol.Value = True Then ans = ans & xcontrol.Caption & ","

Next xcontrol

Anss = Left(ans, Len(ans) - 1)
ActiveSheet.Cells(9, 4).Value = Anss

Exit Sub
M: MsgBox "You have not selected any PPE requirements"
End Sub


To get around the immediate problem, you need to check for "CheckBox".

You have several problems in your code:
(o) VBA doesn't use Lazy evaluation in If-statements
If TypeName(xcontrol) = "Checkbox" And xcontrol.Value = True Then ans = ans & xcontrol.Caption & ","

VBA will always execute both parts of the If statement. That means no matter if a control is a Checkbox or anything else, the check for xcontrol.Value = True will be executed - however, there are controls (eg labels) that don't have a Value-property and therefore you will get a runtime error.
(o) The TypeName for a checkbox is "CheckBox" - that's the reason your code will never find a checkbox and always end up with an empty string.
(o) When nothing was selected, you end up with ans = "". The statement Left(ans, Len(ans) - 1) will fail because Len(ans) - 1 = -1. You should check the length of the string.
(o) Your On Error goto M will jump to the label M no matter what error happens, but you are not analyzing the error. That means that the error caused by the usage of .Value in your If-statement causes the message "You have not selected...", the real reason for that error is hidden. Use Error handling only for real errors, if needed, not for cases that you can catch by yourself (eg no checkbox was selected).
The corrected code could look like this (consider to give the routine a better name, your future ego will thank you for that)
Private Sub Macro42()
    Dim answers As String
    Dim xControl As Control
    For Each xControl In Controls
        If TypeName(xControl) = "CheckBox" Then
            If xControl.Value = True Then
                answers = answers & IIf(answers <> "", ",", "") & xControl.Caption & ","
            End If
        End If
    Next xControl
    If answers = "" Then
        MsgBox "You have not selected any PPE requirements"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Cells(9, 4).Value = Anss
    End If
End Sub

